Shutting a ThreadPoolExecutor down with a KeyboardInterrupt
I'm using Python's ThreadPoolExecutor to implement an asynchronous client. Every so often, the script submits a synchronous client callable to the thread pool. I'd like to be able to stop the loop with a KeyboardInterrupt.
I've written the following code.
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import tritonclient.http as tritonclient

import argparse
import itertools
import logging
import random
import sys
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

distributions = {
    'poisson': lambda w: random.expovariate(1/w),
    'uniform': lambda w: random.uniform(0, 2*w),
}

class Client:
    def __init__(self, url, model):
        self.client = tritonclient.InferenceServerClient(url)
        config = self.client.get_model_config(model)
        self.inputs = config['input']
        self.outputs = [output['name'] for output in config['output']]
        self.model = model

    def __call__(self):
        inputs = []
        for config in self.inputs:
            assert config['data_type'] == 'TYPE_FP32'
            shape = [1] + config['dims']
            datatype = config['data_type'].removeprefix('TYPE_')
            input = tritonclient.InferInput(config['name'], shape, datatype)
            array = np.random.default_rng().random(shape, dtype=np.float32)
            input.set_data_from_numpy(array)
            inputs.append(input)
        result = self.client.infer(self.model, inputs)
        for output in self.outputs:
            result.get_output(output)

def benchmark(fn):
    t_i = time.time()
    fn()
    t_f = time.time()
    print(t_i, t_f - t_i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--distribution', choices=distributions.values(),
                        type=distributions.get, default=lambda w: w)
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--nrequests', default=-1, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--open', '--open-loop', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--url', default='localhost:8000')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='count', default=0)
    parser.add_argument('model')
    rate = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    rate.add_argument('-w', '--wait', '--delay', '-l', '--lambda',
                      default=0, type=float)
    rate.add_argument('-r', '--rate', '-f', '--frequency', type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    level = (logging.DEBUG if args.verbose > 1
            else logging.INFO if args.verbose
            else logging.WARNING)
    logging.basicConfig(level=level)

    if args.rate:
        args.wait = 1/args.rate
    logging.debug(args)

    client = Client(args.url, args.model)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        try:
            for _ in (itertools.count() if args.nrequests < 0
                        else range(args.nrequests)):
                if args.open:
                    executor.submit(benchmark, client)
                else:
                    benchmark(client)
                time.sleep(args.distribution(args.wait))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        except BrokenPipeError:
            pass

It hangs on the first Control-C and requires two more before it finally exits with the following error. For what it's worth, my first use of ChatGPT was today in order to figure this out. It didn't work. What a let-down.
1717617460.23863 0.003475189208984375
1717617460.250774 0.0033867359161376953
1717617460.2690861 0.0033500194549560547
^C^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/pcoppock/mlos/apps/tritonclient", line 73, in <module>
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 649, in __exit__
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 235, in shutdown
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1096, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1116, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1537, in _shutdown
    atexit_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1096, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1116, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt: 

linux$ 


Re, "...ChatGPT..." ChatGPT doesn't know how to solve problems. ChatGPT knows how to construct text (including source code text) that looks like an answer that some reasonable person might have given. But looking like an answer and actually being a correct answer are not always the same thing.

The issue lay with the Triton client module. The Client objects weren't thread-safe. After I modified the code to initialize a new client in every thread, a single ctrl-C eventually stopped the program.

linux sends SIGINT to an arbitrary thread, which bubbles to the main thread, but the main thread has to wait for all threads to end before it terminates, this is why you need the second Ctrl-C.
there is no clean way to fix this, you may want to handle SIGINT and set some boolean to make all threads terminate, but as you are using synchronous IO, you cannot easily interrupt ongoing IO.
the only reliable way is to abruptly terminate the application when the Ctrl-C happens by having the signal handler do os._exit(), which kills the application without doing any cleanup, the OS will close all sockets and reclaim the memory for you.
import sys
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import signal
import os

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print("App killed by Ctrl-C", flush=True)
    os._exit(0)  # KILL THE APPLICATION RIGHT NOW !!

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self):
        start = time.time()
        while time.time() - start < 10:
            pass

def benchmark(fn):
    t_i = time.time()
    fn()
    t_f = time.time()
    print(t_i, t_f - t_i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        try:
            task = executor.submit(benchmark, client)
            task.result()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        except BrokenPipeError:
            pass

while it is generally bad to kill python this way as no cleanup is done, the alternative is to either wait for all tasks to finish, or set a boolean that threads will periodically check, both which won't work in your case.
lastly you may want to use task.result() instead of sleeping for an arbitrary amount of time, to make sure you have properly awaited all tasks and properly bubbled exceptions to the main thread.
note that if you have any child processes from process pools then those won't be cleaned up, you need to properly kill them in the signal handler, so don't use this "trick" as part of a large application.

On the other hand if you just want to "stop new submissions" you can make the handler set a boolean that your main thread can listen on and avoid submitting new tasks.

Yeah, I mostly just want to stop new submissions, so handler is probably the way to go. I still don't understand why the main thread blocks when waiting for the thread pool to shutdown. Once the signal gets delivered to the main thread, why are the other threads blocked?

@PatrickCoppock the threadpool's with scope will block until all workers are joined, that's just how the pool works, if python doesn't do that then the application can end while requests are still happenning which will be bad.
